# how to render data to ejs page for line chart (chartjs, nodejs and express)

Tags: node.js, express, ejs

hi i'm plotting a multi line graph using chartjs. My backend is nodejs and using ejs as my views template. I'm rendering data(array) like this

```
var a = angledata1;
    console.log(a,"asd");  
      res.render("/patientgraph", {
        angledata: a,
         
      });
```

and in my ejs template inside script tag i'm trying to access it by,

```
<script>

   var x = <%- JSON.stringify(angledata) %>;

        var canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
        var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
        
        var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
           type: 'line',
      data:{
        labels: <%- JSON.stringify(x) %>,
  //rest of chartjs code

<script>
```

but i'm always getting this error,

```
ReferenceError: E:\g\views\patientgraph.ejs:54
    52| 
    53| 
 >> 54|    var x = <%- JSON.stringify(angledata) %>;
    55| 
    56|         var canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
    57|         var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

angledata is not defined
```

I tried a lot by declaring the var outside script tag like inside a div and accessing it using inner html. but still doesn't work. please help.

Comment: Try using `locals.angledata` instead.

Comment: nothing bro. now the error is undefined . i tried this snippet .    var x = <%= JSON.stringify(locals.angledata) %>
  console.log(x)    , inside script                  now x is undefined